# Java regex breaking on quotation-mark-containing string

Tags: java, regex

`"\"a".matches("a")` returns false.  What's going on here?

Comment: Question is not comprehensive. Please add examples or explanation

Comment: Neither of your strings contain parentheses?

Comment: @Romaan I deliberately reduced the question to the simplest case possible.  I had a much more complex regular expression that was breaking and I eventually determined that this particular case was causing it not to match.

Comment: @Walker please add a simple example. Thanks

Comment: @mathematical.coffee With escape characters, I essentially have the regular expression 'a' trying to match the string '"a' (ignore single quotation).  When I test that out in other regex implementations, I get a match.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @picklishDoorknob; don't know what I was thinking @mathematical.coffee I meant to say double quotation.  I understand the confusion now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`matches` method expects the *entire* string to match](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), not just a match to exist somewhere inside the target string.

This, on the other hand, [returns](http://ideone.com/lemV8k) `true`, because it lets the string contain anything before or after the match:

```
"\"a".matches(".*a.*")
```

Another way to look for a match anywhere in the string is by using [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) directly:

```
if (Pattern.compile("a").matcher("\"a").find()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you; I couldn't tell from the API docs whether that was the case.  That clears things up immensely!  Also, the Pattern tip is useful; I think I'll use it here so as to avoid cluttering up the regex.